# vuex unknown mutation type: setPatient

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm using vue 3 with composition api and vuex 4, I've done it this way before but now its throwing that error.

**Here's my store/index.js**

```
import { createStore } from "vuex";

export const store = new createStore({

    state: {
        patient: [],
    },

    mutations: {
        setPatient(state, payload) {
            state.patient = payload;
        },
    },

    getters: {
        getPatient(state) {
            return state.patient;
        },
        getAppointment(state) {
            return state.patient.appointments;
        },
    },


})
```

app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

import { createApp, h } from 'vue';
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';
import { InertiaProgress } from '@inertiajs/progress';
import {store} from './Store'
const { RayPlugin } = require('vue-ray');
window.$ = window.jQuery = require("jquery");

const appName = window.document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0]?.innerText || 'Laravel';

createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: (name) => require(`./Pages/${name}.vue`),
    setup({ el, app, props, plugin }) {
        return createApp({ render: () => h(app, props) })
            .use(plugin)
            .use(store)
            .use(RayPlugin, { interceptErrors: true, host: '127.0.0.1', port: 23517 })
            .mixin({ methods: { route } })
            .mount(el);
    },
});

InertiaProgress.init({ color: '#4B5563' });
```

And following the documentation, on my component I did the following:

```
import { useStore } from 'vuex'
import {onMounted, reactive, ref} from "vue";

export default {
 
 props: {
        patient: {
            type: Object,
            required: true
        }
    },

 setup(props) {
     
   const store = useStore();

   onMounted(() => {
     store.commit('setPatient', props.patient);
   })

 }

}
```

So far I've done this before, but using the composition api is new for me, so I couldn't find where the error is